# Using SVGs in Kivy

Tags: python, svg, kivy

I am trying to import an SVG into Kivy to create an interactive component in the page. I have succeeded in getting it on the page but am having trouble doing anything meaningful with it. I can't seem to move it where I want, size it, or change any properties. It won't fit nicely in any layout either. I was wondering if anybody who's used SVGs in Kivy before could give me some pointers. At the moment I have it set up using the class below:

```
class SvgWidget(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SvgWidget, self).__init__()
        filename = 'Z:/Brendan/NIC4/CochleaGraphic.svg'
        with self.canvas:
            svg = Svg(filename)
```

I then use this class as a child widget in my kv lang string. I have tried almost every kivy layout and just can't figure it out. I just want to fit it into my page in a meaningful way. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: In my experience `Svg` does not work. If you [download](https://kivy.org/#download) the current version of `kivy` and try running the apps in the `examples/svg` folder, they all fail.

Comment: That's disheartening but a very good point. Yeah I tried running the examples and they did not even run lol. Do you know of any other method for drawing interactive graphics? I want a picture with clickable elements. It's a relatively simple graphic with a spiral and some circles.

Comment: So the first step is to convert the `.svg` image to some other format that can be displayed. Next, you would need to develop some scheme for determining if a "clickable element" was clicked on. Currently kivy allows you to determine if a mouse click is within a bounding box, so anything more complex than that would be up to you to develop.

Comment: Okay thanks! Are bounding boxes always rectangular? Are there any options in Kivy for non-rectangular bounding boxes or widgets? I'm thinking of switching to PyQt. Kivy feels kinda restricted but maybe I'm missing some key functionality?...

Comment: Yes, bounding boxes are rectangular. If your clickable elements are standard geometric shapes, then you can use geometry to calculate if a click is inside the element. You can use any scheme that you can devise (as long as it can be implemented in python/kivy).